# Passing Stream Parameter with other Parameters to invoke WCF Service through POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

May I ask for an alternative way to include the stream file in passing it as a parameter with other parameters as seen below my code to my WCF service through post method. I'm a beginner so I'm not really sure on how to handle this thing. I intentionally did not put the port number. With my code, I'm encountering this error "System.Web.HttpInputStream' cannot be serialized." that's why I need to find other way to pass parameters.

Client code:

```
                FileVariables fileInput = new FileVariables
                {
                    fileName = FileUpload1.FileName,
                    fileContents = FileUpload1.FileContent,
                    Username = txtUsername.Text,
                    Password = txtPassword.Text
                };


                DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FileVariables));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                json.WriteObject(ms, fileInput);

                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                webClient.UploadString("http://localhost/TestService.svc/REST/UploadFile", "POST", data);
```

WCF Service:

```
  public interface ITestService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadFile",
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   string UploadFile(FileVariables file);
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class FileVariables
  {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string fileName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order =2)]
    public Stream fileContents { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: what type has FileUpload1 ?

Comment: It's a FileUpload tool in aspx

Comment: I am not an expert but I do not think you can send a stream through wcf call. try maybe reading an array of bytes from your FileUpload tool instead.

Answer (score 0):

To have stream members in WCF, Messagecontract must be used. Datacontract and messagecontract are serialized in different ways.If you use Datacontract in a class with stream properties,you will have serialization problems.

For more information,Please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming?redirectedfrom=MSDN

But webhttpbinding does not support Messagecontract, so now you have two ways to solve this problem.

**First solution:**

If you must use webhttpbinding,your interface should look like this:

```
     [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}/{Username}/{Password}")]
    void UploadFile(string fileName,string Username,string Password,Stream fileContents);
```

You can refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/create-a-service-arbitrary-data-using-wcf

**Second solution:**

The second method is to use a binding that supports Messagecontract instead of using webhttpbing, such as basichttpbinding.

```
        [MessageContract]
public class FileVariables
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream fileContents { get; set; }
    [MessageHeader]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [MessageHeader]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is the filevariables class.

**UPDATE**

You can call it like this:

```
        string fileName= "fileName", Username= "Username", Password= "Password";
        string ad = "/UploadFile/" + fileName+"/"+ Username+"/"+ Password;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8012/ServiceModelSamples/service"+ ad);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] fileToSend = new byte[12345];
        for (int i = 0; i < fileToSend.Length; i++)
        {
            fileToSend[i] = (byte)('a' + (i % 26));
        }
        reqStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

If my answer helps you, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: I've used the first solution you proposed and it works. Thank you so much! Apparently, from the client side, I don't know how to pass these parameters properly to invoke the post method. Would you also kindly help me on this?

Comment: Sorry, got an error though. 404 Not found, would you know why that happened?

Comment: There are two possibilities. The first one is that your service did not start successfully. You need to check it. The second one is that your URI may be misspelled.

Comment: You can open the help document in WCF to view the correct URI:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-service-help-page

Comment: I found the error. I'm passing a parameter value to the username = "dom\Username" and I think the slash sign is making the URI invalid. Would you suggest how can I pass a parameter with slash sign on it. Thank you!

Comment: We can't pass parameters with slash symbol, because WCF receives parameters according to slash symbol. WCF thinks that each slash match is a parameter. I think the final solution is you add another parameter to split username.

Comment: to pass parameter with slash sign, add another parameter to your service ex: string filename, string domain, string username, string password, stream fileContent. Or just encode the userName.